# span argument not work working with loess fit in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, loess, facet-grid

I want need to change the span argument in the example plot,[Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WvZD.jpg)

In the code I have written to get this plot I can't get the span to do anything other than the default of 0.2. I have a hunch it's got something to do with assigning the loess fit properly to each of the groups but what I've tried hasn't worked. I've made some example code to demonstrate the span argument not affecting the loess fit below.

```
xy <- rbind(data.frame(x=sort(rnorm(n=46, mean=5, sd=2)), y=1:46),data.frame(x=sort(rnorm(n=46, mean=7, sd=3)), y=1:46), data.frame(x=sort(rnorm(n=46, mean=4, sd=7)), y=1:46))


plot.data <- data.frame(group=letters[rep(1:3, each=46)], xy)

ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_smooth(method=loess, span=0.1, se=T,  col='black') + geom_point(alpha=0.7) + facet_wrap(~group)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Span is related to the geom_smooth(...) method call "loess", see this [link](https://medium.com/@ODSC/comparing-five-different-smooths-which-one-rules-them-all-5fa1578fb09a#:%7E:text=Loess%20wins.&text=Unsurprisingly%20the%20GAM%20fits%20our,to%20GAM%20or%20another%20method) for a helpful intro.

Any data over 1000 data points defaults to method = "gam", as this is more efficient for large data sets.

```
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam'
```

Try explicitly stating method = loess, and then setting the span.

```
geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.3)
```

Note: This exponentially increases the chart render time.

Comment: Thanks spotnag. I realise I didn't mark this as completed early. Your answer is spot on and succinct and may help others. The problem I had was I hadn't noticed a lack of comments around method =  loess. R didn't return any errors or warnings, it just didn't show what I wanted which left me very confused. Usually some red text reminds me that I've done something wrong.

Comment: No worries, glad you sorted your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this probably has less to do with `ggplot2` and more to do with your data. Observe:

```
plot.data.a <- plot.data[plot.data$group == 'a', ]
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for(i in seq(.1, .9, length.out = 4)){
    plot(plot.data.a[,-1], main = paste('Span of', round(i, 2)))
    lines(loess(y ~ x, data = plot.data.a, span = i))
}
```

[image]

It seems as though varying the span has little to no *visual* impact of the `loess` fit.

So, as you were making your plots and varying the `span`, it seems likely that `ggplot2` understood you were changing the `span`, it's just that the fits were relatively unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, it's helped me look at this from a different angle. I realise my 'example data' was a bit rubbish which also didn't help matters.

Comment: I've found the problem comes to the method= argument in the geom_smooth. I hadn't put loess in side quotation marks. If you run the code at the top again with method="loess" then the span argument works, it's subtle for this data but on the data I need it to work in it works perfectly.